# How do Actor Systems function to prevent memory overflow from queues but also prevent threads blocking on writing on the queues?

Tags: erlang, akka, message-queue, distributed-computing, actor

Actors send messages to one another. If the queues are limited, then what happens on write/send attempts to full queues? Blocking or dropping? If they are not limited, a memory crash is possible. How much is configurable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default mailboxes in Akka are not bounded, so will not prevent memory crash. You can however configure actors to use different mailboxes, among those there are both mailboxes that discard (pass to dead letters) messages when the max size is reached and those that block (I would not recommend to use those). You can find all mailbox implementations that comes with Akka in the docs here: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/mailboxes.html#mailbox-implementations

Comment: Indeed. ActorSystems cannot be backpressured, unless the applications logic does so, but Reactive Streams is the way to go for backpressured apps, like AkkaStreams, which uses Akka ActorSystems under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

You can test easily the behavior of the Erlang VM in this situation. In the shell:

```
F = fun F() -> receive done -> ok end end,
P = spawn(F),
G = fun G(Pid,Size,Wait) -> Pid ! lists:seq(1,Size), receive done -> ok after Wait -> G(Pid,Size,Wait) end end,
H = fun(Pid,Size,Wait) -> T = fun() -> G(Pid,Size,Wait) end, spawn(T) end,
D = fun D() -> io:format("~p~n~p~n",[erlang:time(),erlang:memory(processes_used)]), receive done -> ok after 10000 -> D() end end,
P1 = spawn(D).

P2 = H(P,100000,5).
```

You will see that you get a memory allocation exception, the VM writes a core dump and crashes.

I didn't check how to modify the limits, if you make the trial, you will see that it needs to reach a very high number of messages, using tens gigabytes of memory in the mailbox.

If you ever reach this situation, I don't think the first reaction is to increase the size, you should look first for

- unread messages,
- process bottleneck
- application architecture
- is Erlang adapted to your problem
- ...

Answer (score 1):

actor queue in erlang not have limitation, this limited by memory size of VM, if memory size in VM is full VM crashed. for monitor or and management memory allocation and cpu load you can use [os_mon](http://erlang.org/doc/man/os_mon_app.html) in Erlang

you can test in erlang shell

```erlang
F = fun() -> timer:sleep(60000),
             {message_queue_len, InboxLen} = erlang:process_info(self(), message_queue_len),
              io:format("Len ===> ~p", [InboxLen]) 
    end.
PID = erlang:spawn(F).
[PID ! "hi" || _ <- lists:seq(1, 50000)].
```

if you increase number of message you can overflow memory

Answer (score 1):

Default mailboxes in Akka are not bounded. But if you want to limit the max messages in mailboxes, you could build an Akka stream in the actor, then OverflowStrategy can be used on demand.

For example:

```
val source: Source[Message, SourceQueueWithComplete[Message]] =
    Source.queue[Message](bufferSize = 8192,
      overflowStrategy = OverflowStrategy.dropNew)
```